# Question about specific volume integral.

Tags: calculus

So I need to evaluate the following volume integral, and I'm not sure which bounds to use and that makes the question kind of vague for me at least.

I've tried to solve it myself, but each try leaves my with a different solution, so I was wondering if someone could show me how to do the following question:

> Determine the value of $\iiint_Wz^2dV$, where $W$ is the solide region around the cone $z^2=3x^2+3y^2$ and inside the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 6z$.

Comment: You should perhaps show what you attempted.

Comment: When you have a minute, please look at [how to format mathematics here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on Math SE. Also, I suggest that you bookmark this [very useful MathJax page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 
for quick reference. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\iiint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{3}}z^{2}\bracks{z^{2} > 3x^{2} + 3y^{2}}
\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} < 6z}\bracks{z > 0}\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{2}\iint_{\large\mathbb{R}^{2}}
\bracks{z^{2} > 3x^{2} + 3y^{2}}\bracks{x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} < 6z}
\,\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{z^{2} > 3r^{2}}\bracks{r^{2} + z^{2} < 6z}
r\,\dd r\,\dd\phi\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{r < \min\braces{{1 \over 3}\,z^{2},6z - z^{2}}}\,\dd r\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{2}\braces{%
\bracks{z < {9 \over 2}}{1 \over 3}\,z^{2} +
\bracks{z > {9 \over 2}}\pars{6z - z^{2}}\bracks{6 - z > 0}}\dd z
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\int_{0}^{9/2}z^{4}\,\dd z +
\pi\int_{9/2}^{6}\pars{6z^{3} - z^{4}}\,\dd z =
\bbx{\ds{{8505 \over 32}\,\pi}} \approx 834.9764
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

How do you find limits of integration?

Inside the sphere... this is asking for spherical coordinates.

$x = \rho \cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y = \rho \sin\theta\sin\phi\\
z = \rho\cos\phi$

now plug these into the equations given.

$z^2 = 3x^2 + 3y^2\\
\rho^2 \cos^2\phi = 3\rho^2 \cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + 3\rho^2 \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi\\
\rho^2\cos^2\phi = 3\rho^2\sin^2\phi\\
\tan^2\phi = 3\\
\phi = \arctan\frac 1{\sqrt 3}
$

$x^2 + y^2 +z^2 =6z \\
\rho^2 \cos^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2 \sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi + \rho^2\cos^2\phi = 6\rho\cos\phi\\
\rho^2 = 6\rho\cos\phi\\
\rho(\rho-6\cos\phi) = 0$

Comment: The ϕ you found, is that the upper or lower limit? And how do you find them both? Since this is only one. And since tan=sin/cos shouldnt $\phi = \arctan\sqrt {1/3}$ instead of $\sqrt3$?

Comment: @Amaluena Ineed $\phi = \arctan \sqrt {\frac 13} = \frac {\pi}{6},$ Thanks.    We want the region above the cone... if $z =  \cos \phi$, which side of $\frac {\pi}{6}$ is above the cone?

Comment: Hmm, I think everything "inside" this angle, so I think $\phi$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/ 6$, right?

Comment: That would be correct.